# Pyspark dataframe error, cannot work psdf.show()

Tags: pyspark

The psdf.show() does not work although DataFrame looks to be created. I wonder what is the cause of this.

The environment is

- Pyspark:3.2.1-hadoop3.2
- Hadoop:3.2.1
- JDK: 18.0.1.1
- local

The code is the below

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .master('local')\
        .appName('test')\
        .getOrCreate()

from datetime import datetime, date
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import Row

psdf = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 2., 'string1', date(2000, 1, 1), datetime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0)),
    (2, 3., 'string2', date(2000, 2, 1), datetime(2000, 1, 2, 12, 0)),
    (3, 4., 'string3', date(2000, 3, 1), datetime(2000, 1, 3, 12, 0))
], schema='a long, b double, c string, d date, e timestamp')

psdf.show()
```

and the error message is

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
    Input In [7], in <cell line: 1>()
    ----> 1 psdf.show()
    
    File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py:494, in DataFrame.show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
        491     raise TypeError("Parameter 'vertical' must be a bool")
        493 if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
    --> 494     print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
        495 else:
        496     try:
    
    File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1321, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
       1315 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
       1316     self.command_header +\
       1317     args_command +\
       1318     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
       1320 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    -> 1321 return_value = get_return_value(
       1322     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
       1324 for temp_arg in temp_args:
       1325     temp_arg._detach()
    
    File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py:111, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
        109 def deco(*a, **kw):
        110     try:
    --> 111         return f(*a, **kw)
        112     except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
        113         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)
    
    File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
        324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
        325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
    --> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
        327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
        328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
        329 else:
        330     raise Py4JError(
        331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
        332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))
    
    Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o43.showString.
    : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (XXXX.XXX.co.jp executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:162)
.......
```

If you know the solution, would you give me the advice to solve the problem?

Comment: I checked it out it works. Follow this [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AQpew_8PKPn0G14tBErgyT833OqIHg9R?usp=sharing)

Comment: I copied the code on the local, but unfortunately the same error message was returned

Comment: Review your `.show` calls. This method has a parameter `vertical` which you seem to have set somewhere and it is not boolean. `show` definition: `def show(self, n=20, truncate=True, vertical=False)`